# Load data when user click on a button(last row is missing)

Tags: javascript, php, angular

When the limit reach length-1 the last data is not being retrieved from the database I don't know why, but I'm getting 2 rows each time the user clicks on the loading button, here is an example [Check my website](http://newsite.uftam.net/uftam_actuality)

This is my PHP code:

```
$query = $this->connect()->prepare(
            "SELECT e.*, t.*
            FROM t_event e join t_type_event t using(tte_id)
            WHERE tte_lib = :lib
            ORDER BY eve_lib ASC
            LIMIT :start, :limit;"
        );
        $query->bindValue(':lib', 'first', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindValue(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();
        return $query;
```

and this is my angular code:

```
limit: number = 4;
start: number = 1;
loadArticles(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (this.limit <= this.indexedEventsLength - 1) {
      this.limit += 2;
      this._formation.displaySecondEvents_indexed(this.start, this.limit).subscribe(
        (data: Formation[]) => {
          this.indexedEvents = data;
        },
        error => {
          console.log("error trying to get indexed events");
        }
      )
    } else {
      const Toast = Swal.mixin({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top-end',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 3000,
        timerProgressBar: true,
        onOpen: (toast) => {
          toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
          toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
        }
      })

      Toast.fire({
        icon: 'info',
        title: "Il n'y a plus d'articles"
      })
    }
  }
```

I'm loading 4 articles at the start and when the user clicks on the button, I load 2 more articles. the problem here is that when there's 1 article left in my database, and the limit will be incremented by 2 that last row will be ignored for some reason. any help will be appreciated, please.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems like typical by-one-off error. If you use limit 1,2 then from two lines it can return only one. limit 0,2 should return you both. Have you tried to lower the first digit by one?

Comment: Oh thank you so much man I'm so idiot forgot that it starts at 0 not 1 thanks a lot.